# Replace element with new one in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to replace my `<input>` element with a new one, in order to clear it. This is in my render method:

```
let fileInput = null
fileInput = (
  <input id={this.props.name} key={performance.now()} accept="image/*" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="file"/>
)

return fileInput
```

`render()` is called each time I select an item (due to the component itself updating info displayed) and therefore should replace the `<input>` with a new one, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: are you sure it is entering your render() method every time?

Comment: Yes I checked it with `console.log`

Comment: what is the part is not changing? performance.now() I suppose? Can you put that code? And did you check the value of it also with console.log?

Comment: `performance.now()` is always unique, it will always return a new value in my case. And yes I did check. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Don't think will help, but maybe you can try to get the performance.now() stored into a variable first, and then put the variable into the key. I can not really figure out what can be wrong there :/

Comment: No, that will definitely have no effect.